# BIOS ACPI error when dual booting Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bios

I have Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 installed on two different SSDs. The OS boots fine after error. What is causing it? I have a new model of CPU (Core i7 12700K).

[image: Picture of bios error]

Comment: If the OS boots fine and is otherwise working normally, it is perfectly safe to ignore errors/warnings on boot. They are a normal occurrence and not something to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

ACPI error is only a problem when you're using a realy old computer.
If this error stops the computer from booting, you can try to boot with ACPI off (if you have that option).

But this seems to be a common error which isn't fatal.